# document.getElementById("clock") is null?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

In following code `document.getElementById("clock")` is **null**, How can it be solved?

```
    var interval = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);
    function clock() {
        var date = new Date();
        var hourOffset = 3;
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes());
        var time = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 2, 22);
        var dstStart = date.getTime();
        date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear(), 8, 22);
        var dstEnd = date.getTime();
        if(time > dstStart && time < dstEnd)
            hourOffset = 4;
        date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + hourOffset, date.getUTCMinutes() + 30);
        var output = date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = output;
    }
```

Comment: And is there an element of the `id` of `clock` in your document?

Comment: Do you have an element on the page with `id="clock"`? Pretty much the only reason that returns null is if the element doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need an element with id "clock", secondly, you need to execute that code after the DOM is ready, not before because otherwise JS won't find the element.

In other words... add:

```
<div id='clock'></div>
```

And paste that javascript code before the `</body>` in your document.

Answer (score 3):

You must have an item in your code with the id `clock`, try adding this to your html:

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Additionally, it would be helpful to see your html.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason `getElementById` would return `undefined` is if there is no HTML element available with the id `clock`.  Ensure one of the elements has this ID

```
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div id="clock"></div>` to your page. That is where the clock will show up.

If you need more help, please post the HTML code of your whole page.

You can do it differently too if you like, for example, any one of

```
<b id="clock"></b>
<span id="clock"></span>
<div style="color:blue" id="clock"></div>
```